# Go get values from .env file

Tags: go

Hello I'm not getting values ​​from an .env file in my go project, could someone help me?

**.env:**

```
API_PORT=8080
DB_HOST=db             
DB_DRIVER=postgres
DB_USER=go
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_NAME=go123
DB_PORT=5432
```

**db:**

```
func getURI() string {
    fmt.Println("port:", os.Getenv("go123"), os.Getenv("DB_HOST"))
    dbPort, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("DB_PORT"))
    fmt.Println(dbPort)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error on load db port from env:", err.Error())
        dbPort = 5432
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
        dbPort,
        os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
        os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
        os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
}
```

**error:**

> 2021/04/24 21:02:12 error on load db port from env: strconv.Atoi:
> parsing "": invalid syntax 2021/04/24 21:02:12 failed to connect to
> `host=/var/run/postgresql user=gbcdev database=`: dial error (dial
> unix /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or
> directory)

The connection to my postgres is normal, but my envs are always arriving as empty

I'm forgetting something?

Comment: you need to load/parse this .env file some way at startup. Maybe use something like https://github.com/joho/godotenv

Comment: why not use  `embed` + `json.Parse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you are using [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv) module and forgot to call the Load method first?

```golang
import (
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "os"
)

func getURI() string {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    
    // now you can use os.Getenv ...     
}
```